# Resize image in python without using resize() - nearest neighbor

Tags: python, image, resize, rgb

For an assignment I want to resize a .jpg image with a python code, but without using the pil.image.resize() function or another similar function. I want to write the code myself but I can't figure out how. The image is RGB. I have found this can be solved by nearest neighbor interpolation (as well as other methods but this one is fine for my specific assignment). The height and the width should both be able to be made bigger or smaller. So far I only have this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib as plt
import math
import PIL
from PIL import Image

img = np.array(Image.open("foto1.jpg"))          

height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
dim = img.shape[2]  

new_h = int(input("New height: "))  
new_w = int(input("New width: "))  

imgR = img[:,:,0] #red pixels
imgG = img[:,:,1] #green pixels
imgB = img[:,:,2] #blue pixels

newR = np.empty([new_h, new_w])             
newG = np.empty([new_h, new_w])            
newB = np.empty([new_h, new_w])
```

So now all three colours have a new array of the right dimensions. Unfortunately on the web I can only find people who use resize() functions... Does anyone know?

Thank in advance!

Comment: There are lots of algorithms for resizing an image, and many of them are very complex.  Which do you want to use?  There's a reason people use libraries to do this.

Comment: I think nearest neighbor is allright for this assignment. It seems the easiest.

Comment: Definitely the easiest, also the ugliest.  Thanks for filling in that detail.

Comment: Yes, so I have seen in videos explaining the different methods. I've just started trying to learn image processing so I am taking small steps. Hopefully I will be able to try and code better looking images eventually :)

Comment: You've got your output array,  now you need to fill it. So you are going to need to loop over all pixels of the output array and write something in each. Think about what to write... if you are half way across and a third of the way down your output image, which pixel from the input image would you want there?

Answer (score 1):

The key to doing any image transformation like resizing is to have a mapping from output coordinates to input coordinates.  Then you can simply iterate over the entire output and grab a pixel from the input.  Nearest neighbor makes this particularly easy, because there's never a need to interpolate a pixel that doesn't lie exactly on integer coordinates - you simply round the coordinates to the nearest integer.

```
for new_y in range(new_h):
    old_y = int(round(new_y * (new_h - 1) / (height - 1)))
    if old_y < 0: old_y = 0
    if old_y >= height: old_y = height - 1
    for new_x in range(new_w):
        old_x = int(round(new_x * (new_w - 1) / (width - 1)))
        if old_x < 0: old_x = 0
        if old_x >= width: old_x = width - 1
        newR[new_y,new_x] = imgR[old_y,old_x]
        newG[new_y,new_x] = imgG[old_y,old_x]
        newB[new_y,new_x] = imgB[old_y,old_x]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code could do the trick.

```
def resize_img(image, resize_width, resize_height):
    """
    :params
        image: shape -> (width, height, channels)
        resize_width: The resize width dimension. 
        resize_height: The resize height dimension. 
    
    :returns
        array of shape -> (resized_width, resized_height, channels)
    """
    
    original_width, original_height, channel = image.shape
    
    red_channel   = image[:, :, 0]
    green_channel = image[:, :, 1]
    blue_channel  = image[:, :, 2]
    
    resized_image = np.zeros((resize_width, resize_height, channel), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    x_scale = original_width/resize_width
    y_scale = original_height/resize_height
    
    resize_idx = np.zeros((resize_width, resize_height))
    resize_index_x = np.ceil(np.arange(0, original_width, x_scale)).astype(int)
    resize_index_y = np.ceil(np.arange(0, original_height, y_scale)).astype(int)
    resize_index_x[np.where(resize_index_x == original_width)]  -= 1
    resize_index_y[np.where(resize_index_y == original_height)] -= 1

    resized_image[:, :, 0] = red_channel[resize_index_x, :][:, resize_index_y]
    resized_image[:, :, 1] = green_channel[resize_index_x, :][:, resize_index_y]
    resized_image[:, :, 2] = blue_channel[resize_index_x, :][:, resize_index_y]
    
    return resized_image
```

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65154879/using-opencv-resize-multiple-the-same-size-of-images-at-once-in-python/73468091#73468091